# How to create a custom combox with popup?

Tags: uwp-xaml

Combo-box popup should always open below and show a title in the popup. Is their any way to do that.[image]

Answer (score 0):

> How to add 'Select a Title' in that popup

You could edit its [default style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299116.aspx). **'Go to -> Document Outline in visual studio -> Right click your ComboBox -> Edit Style -> Edit a Copy'**

You could see the Popup control(named as 'x:Name="Popup"') in its ControlTemplate.

Then, you could add a TextBlock in it like the following:

```
<Popup x:Name="Popup">
     <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" BackgroundSizing="OuterBorderEdge" Background="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownBackground}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownBorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownBorderBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,-1,0,-1" Padding="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownBorderPadding}">
           <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Selecte a Title"></TextBlock>
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownForeground}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" MinWidth="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownContentMinWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" VerticalSnapPointsType="OptionalSingle" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Near" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                <ItemsPresenter Margin="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownContentMargin}" />
                </ScrollViewer>
           </StackPanel>
     </Border>
</Popup>
```

> How to always open the popup below the combobox

With the default combobox, it's impossible. As the popup's 'open/close' state is controlled in combobox's code-behind, you cannot change it. But you could choose to make a custom control to achieve it.

For example, you could refer to the XAML layout in the default style and make a [UserControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol).

You could check my simple code sample:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="AppCombobox.MyComboBox"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="using:AppCombobox"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="EditableText" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" />
        <FontIcon
            x:Name="DropDownGlyph"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="0,10,10,10"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
            FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
            FontSize="12"
            Foreground="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownGlyphForeground}"
            Glyph="&#xE0E5;"
            IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        <Popup
            x:Name="Popup"
            Grid.Row="1"
            IsOpen="True">
            <Border
                x:Name="PopupBorder"
                Margin="0,-1,0,-1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Background="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownBackground}"
                BackgroundSizing="OuterBorderEdge"
                BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownBorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownBorderThickness}"
                Padding="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownBorderPadding}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Selecte a Title" />
                    <ScrollViewer
                        x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                        Foreground="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownForeground}"
                        VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Near"
                        VerticalSnapPointsType="OptionalSingle"
                        ZoomMode="Disabled">
                        <ListView Margin="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownContentMargin}" x:Name="list"></ListView>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

For the specific code logic, you need to code it by yourself in its code-behind.